# Extending a boder past a fixed width using CSS

Tags: html, css

Wanted to ask a question in regards to help coming up with a solution on extending the border-top on an element past a fixed width of a container set to `width: 1024px;`. All while keeping the content on the center of the page, aligned to the left.

Thank you!

**Below is the code**

**Html**

```
<main>
    <div>
      <span>Hello</span>
    </div>

  </main>
```

**CSS**

```
main {
margin: 0 auto;
width:1024px;

}


div {
  float:left;
  width:50%;
  transition:all 0.4s ease;

}

div:hover {
 background:red;
}
```

Comment: Fiddle is empty, isn't?

Comment: @guinatal yea it was a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make a element's border extend past the dimensions of that element. But you can make your `div` break out of `main` by using `position: absolute;`.

Example:

```
div {
  float:left;
  width:60%;
  transition:all 0.4s ease;
  border-top: solid black 5px;
  position: absolute;
}
```